# I can't add epubcheck jar to my code in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

In the folder Libraries I added the folder that contains the jar file of epubcheck (http://code.google.com/p/epubcheck/). But for some reason it does not work.

I also added this line of code:

```
import com.adobe.epubcheck.api;
```

Am I missing something?

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE**

Even with all the jars in the Libraries folder... It still does not work.

[image]

Here is the instructions for adding lib to the code from epubchecker README:

> USING AS A LIBRARY
>
> You can also use EpubCheck as a library in your Java application.
>   EpubCheck public interfaces can be found in com.adobe.epubcheck.api
>   package. EpubCheck class can be used to instantiate a validation
>   engine. Use one of its constructors and then call validate() method.
>   Report is an interface that you can implement to get a list of the
>   errors and warnings reported by the validation engine (instead of the
>   error list being printed out).

**OUTPUT**

```
deps-jar:
Created dir: /Users/.../NetBeansProjects/epubValidation/build
Updating property file: /Users/.../NetBeansProjects/epubValidation/build/built-jar.properties
Created dir: /Users/.../NetBeansProjects/epubValidation/build/classes
Created dir: /Users/.../NetBeansProjects/epubValidation/build/empty
Created dir: /Users/.../NetBeansProjects/epubValidation/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
Compiling 1 source file to /Users/.../NetBeansProjects/epubValidation/build/classes
/Users/.../NetBeansProjects/epubValidation/src/epubvalidation/EpubValidation.java:6: package com.adobe.epubcheck does not exist
import com.adobe.epubcheck.api;
1 error
/Users/.../NetBeansProjects/epubValidation/nbproject/build-impl.xml:915: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/.../NetBeansProjects/epubValidation/nbproject/build-impl.xml:268: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 9 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import the epubcheck you need to do the following:

[image: Create a new Java project...]

Create a new Java project... Unchecked **Create Main Class**, this is the only way to make it work.

[image: Right click on Libraries]

Right click on Libraries to select Add JAR/Folder...

[image: Add JAR]

Add JAR...

[image: Add the rest of the JARs]

Add the other JARs.

[image: New File...]

New File... New Class...

[image: New Class...]

Make sure that the package input is empty.

[image: Write the code...]

Write the import...

There you go.

I am not really sure why you have to do it this way... But that is the only way I found to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `/Users/...` entry from your libraries. Adding a folder in the classpath doesn't add all the jars in that folder, it adds the folder *as if it were a jar.* It's trying to read that folder as if it contains the .class files, which is incorrect. Instead, select the external jars option and add all the jars in `lib`, much like how you probably added the epubcheck jar.

An alternative: use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). It will do all this library management for you, and Netbeans makes it pretty easy to use. [Here's a tutorial](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-quickstart.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have already done the following:
    a) Add the epubcheck jar to Libraries
      right-click on Libraries & select "Add JAR/Folder...",  navigate inside your directory
      /Users/xxx/epubcheck-3.0b5-db & select epubcheck-3.0b5.jar
    b) Add the entire epubcheck folder to Libraries
      right-click on Libraries & select "Add JAR/Folder...",  navigate to directory
      /Users/xxx/epubcheck-3.0b5-db & select it

a) is correct
b) is incorrect - you should add each individual jar file within /Users/xxx/epubcheck-3.0b5-db/lib

To correct, do this within Netbeans:
    c) Remove (b) as follows
       right-click Libraries->/Users/xxx/epubcheck-3.0b5_db and select Remove.
    d) Add batik-css-1.7.jar within epubcheck lib folder to Libraries
      right-click on Libraries & select "Add JAR/Folder...",  navigate to directory
      /Users/xxx/epubcheck-3.0b5-db/lib & select batik-css-1.7.jar
    e) repeat (d) for each of batik-util-1.7.jar, commons-compress-1.2.jar, jing-20120227.jar, sac-1.3.jar, saxon-9.1.0.8.jar

Alternative Solution
You could add all of /Users/xxx/epubcheck-3.0b5_db as a separate Netbeans project:
i) copy/move /Users/xxx/epubcheck-3.0b5_db to
netbeansWorkspaceFolder/epubcheck-3.0b5/epubcheck-3.0b5
ii) move epubcheck-3.0b5.jar to netbeansWorkspaceFolder/epubcheck-3.0b5/epubcheck-3.0b5/dist/epubcheck-3.0b5.jar
iii) add it as a Netbeans project:
Add Project -> Java -> Java with existing Sources -> Next ->
set project name=epubcheck-3.0b5 -> Browse -> select epubcheck-3.0b5 directory -> Next ->
for source package folder select "Add Folder..." and select "epubcheck-3.0b5/epubcheck-3.0b5" -> Next ->
Included files list should now show all required lib jars (lib/*.jar) -> Finish
iv) select epubValidation project -> Libraries folder & right-click & select "Add Project..." & select "epubcheck-3.0b5" project
v) Now dist/epubcheck-3.0b5.jar of the lib jars within epubcheck-3.0b5 are available to epubValidation

=B)

Comment: I have tried the first way you propose... And nothing... Look at what I did, under UPDATE.

Comment: What is the problem?  Importing & compiling classes in Netbeans?  Building & deployment error?  Error at runtime?  Please be specific & show the error / code causing the error.  No code & description = no debugging :-)

Comment: I put up a screenshot with the error... Here is what happens when I do a compile: /Users/.../NetBeansProjects/epubValidation/src/epubvalidation/EpubValidation.java:6: package com.adobe.epubcheck does not exist
import com.adobe.epubcheck.api;
1 error